# Strange first time scroll delay in Chrome using jQuery ScrollTop animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have a strange scroll issue in Chrome with one of the project (http://dev.sreejesh.in/wpissue/) I'm working with.

In Google Chrome, when clicking on the link ("The Project") first time, the page scroll with a 1 second delay. After one scroll the issue will never appear again until the page is reloaded. In Firefox it works perfectly.

I use following code

**HTML**

```
<li class="fleft" style="opacity: 1;">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="theprojects inpagelink">The Projects</a>
</li>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.theprojects').click(function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#main").offset().top }, 1000);
});
```

Go here - http://dev.sreejesh.in/wpissue/ & click "The Projects"  or "About Us" link, u will see the issue in chrome.

*OS = Windows 10  | Chrome Version = 46.0.2490.86

Please help

Comment: Have you tried animating only `html`? Also try reading the `$("#main").offset().top` into a variable before animation starts. Chrome may be stumbling on too many DOM searches.

Comment: @Zealander just tried it. When use 'html' it stopped scrolling, Even using just 'body'  didn't help. Also tried variable. See the code here - http://dev.sreejesh.in/wpissue/wp-content/themes/inhouse/js/functions.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the y/scrollTop position value, use it directly and don't read it from the DOM. Measuring things is expensive.

```
$('.theprojects').click(function(){
  var scrollTop = 600;
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: scrollTop }, 1000);
});
```

Consider using using smooth [`element.scrollTo()` API](http://blog.gospodarets.com/native_smooth_scrolling/) instead of jQuery. Perhaps fallback to jquery or don't animate at all in old browsers.

ALSO: Images are too large. One is over 3mb. These should be scaled down and compressed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt reply. Static value didn't helped (http://dev.sreejesh.in/wpissue/wp-content/themes/inhouse/js/functions.js). Seems like element.scrollTo() API doesn't have any support in Chrome yet.

Comment: Optimizing the image in the page solved the issue.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Finally the issue got solved by the suggestion made by Wilson Page. It was the non optimized images in the page caused the issue. After optimizing the images, the scroll works smoothly in the Chrome without making any script change.